# Injecting spring data repository into spring cloud function

Tags: spring-data, spring-cloud-function

I would like to use spring data repository functionality within the spring cloud function.

I've cloned the spring cloud function with azure provider: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-function/tree/2.2.x/spring-cloud-function-samples/function-sample-azure

I have it running locally as well as on azure.

I would like to do the following:

```
public class FooHandler extends AzureSpringBootRequestHandler<Foo, Bar> {

    @Autowired
    private FooRepository fooRepository;

    @FunctionName("uppercase")
    public Bar execute(
        @HttpTrigger(name = "req", methods = { HttpMethod.POST}, authLevel = AuthorizationLevel.FUNCTION) HttpRequestMessage<Optional<Foo>> foo,
        ExecutionContext context) {
        fooRepository.insert(foo.getBody().get());      
        return handleRequest(foo.getBody().get(), context);
    }

}
```

Example mongo repo:

```
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository;

public interface FooRepository extends MongoRepository<Foo, String> {
}
```

The result is NullPointerException. Any idea whether it's possible with spring cloud functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are injecting it in the wrong place. FooHandler is just a delegate to invoke `uppercase` function. So instead inject it into the function itself.

```
@Bean
public Function<Foo, Bar> uppercase(FooRepository fooRepository) {
    return foo -> {
        // do whatever you need with fooRepository
        return new Bar(foo.getValue().toUpperCase());
    };
}
```